# Найдите ошибку в коде, пожалуйста!

Tags: python, python-3.x

Напишите программу, которая проверяет чек из магазина. На чеке указано, по каким ценам и в каком количестве куплены товары, общая стоимость данного товара (т. е. данной позиции в чеке), а также суммарная итоговая стоимостью. Конечно, по цене и количеству можно узнать стоимость, и суммарную стоимость тоже можно рассчитать. Программа должна проверить, правильно ли рассчитана стоимость каждой позиции и правильно ли рассчитана общая сумма, и если присутствуют ошибки, то указать, где именно.
Формат ввода:
На первой строке записано количество позиций N (оно меньше 1000 и дополнено справа пробелами, чтобы достигнуть длины в 4 символа) и общая сумма (целое число).
Далее следует N позиций чека, каждая из которых записана на отдельной строке и соответствует покупке нескольких единиц некоторого товара. 
Сначала записана цена товара (она дополнена справа пробелами до 7 символов), затем знак «*», затем количество этих товаров (оно дополнено справа пробелами до 4 символов), затем знак «=», затем стоимость данной позиции.
Формат вывода.
Нужно вывести разность между указанной итоговой суммой и истинной суммой стоимостей по всем позициям.
Далее нужно вывести в порядке возрастания номера всех позиций (нумерация с 1), в которых указанная стоимость расходится со стоимостью, которую можно рассчитать из цены и количества товара.
Что тут не так?

```
s = input()

n, total = int(s[:4]), int(s[4:])

errors, true_total = [], 0    

for i in range(n):

    s = input()

    price, amount, cost = int(s[:7]), int(s[8:12]), int(s[13:])

    if price * amount != cost:

        errors.append(i+1)

    true_total += cost


print(total - true_total)

for x in errors:

    print(x, end=' ')
```

Ввод:

```
3 2300

99 *2 =199

20 *100 =2000

11 *4 =55
```

У меня выводится:

```
46

1 3
```

Должно:

```
58

1 3
```

Comment: попробуйте более информативные заголовки использовать [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наверное
не

```
true_total += cost
```

а

```
true_total +=  price * amount
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, помогло.

Comment: поставьте галочку